# What is the complexity of counting Hamiltonian cycles of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, hamiltonian-graphs

Since deciding whether a graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle is $NP$-complete, the counting problem which counts the number of such cycles of a graph is $NP$-hard.

Is it also $PP$-hard in the sense that $PP\subseteq P^{\#HAM-CYCLE}$?

Comment: This may help: The TCS post [A decision problem related to the problem of counting Hamiltonian cycles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8249/337) shows that deciding which of a pair of graphs has more H-cycles is PP-hard.

Comment: All I can get from the answer of that question is that the comparative version is $PP$-easy. It is $NP$-hard by setting $G_2$ to have no H-cycle.

Answer (score 3):

In this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82194209.pdf), Liskiewicz et al. state their Lemma 4 as follows:

> **Lemma 4**: The problem of counting Hamiltonian paths in planar graphs of max-deg $\Delta=3$ is $\#P$-complete under $\leq^p_{r-shift}$-reductions.

And, the definition of $\leq^p_{r-shift}$-reductions is as follows:

> **DEFINITION**: **Polynomial-time Right-bit-Shift Reduction**
>
> Let $f,g:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, $f$ is poly-time right-bit-shift reducible to $g$, denoted $f\leq^p_{r-shift}g$, if there exists a poly-time computable function $R_3:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ and a polynomial-time computable function $R_1:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\Sigma^*$, such that $f(x)=g(R_1(x))\mathrm{div}\ 2^{R_3(x)}$, for all $x$.

So, yes, $PP\subseteq P^{\#HAM-CYCLE}$.